# Usando $this quando não está no contexto do objeto

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou tentando criar uma classe em PHP que conecta no banco MySQL e estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context

#### ConnectDB.class.php

```
class ConnectDB
{
    public $pdo;
    private $driver, $host, $port, $base, $user, $pass;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setDriver('mysql');
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort('3306');
        $this->setBase('bsn');
        $this->setUser('root');
        $this->setPass('');
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("{$this->getDriver()}:host={$this->getHost()};port={$this->getPort()};dbname={$this->getBase()}", $this->getUser(), $this->getPass());
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Ocorreu um erro na conexão com o banco de dados.');
        }
    }

    public function setDriver($str) {
        $this->driver = $str;
    }

    public function setHost($str) {
        $this->host = $str;
    }

    public function setPort($str)   {
        $this->port = $str;
    }

    public function setBase($str)   {
        $this->base = $str;
    }

    public function setUser($str)   {
        $this->user = $str;
    }

    public function setPass($str)   {
        $this->pass = $str;
    }

    public function getPDO()    {
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    public function getDriver() {
        return $this->driver;
    }

    public function getHost() {
        return $this->host;
    }

    public function getPort() {
        return $this->port;
    }

    public function getBase() {
        return $this->base;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getPass() {
        return $this->pass;
    }
}
```

#### ManipulateData.class.php

```
require_once('ConnectDB.class.php');
require_once('ITemplate.php');

class ManipulateData extends ConnectDB implements ITemplate
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function select($query) {
        $stmt = parent::getPDO()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    public static function insert($query) {}

    public static function update($query) {}

    public static function delete($query) {}

    public static function doubleData($dados) {}
}
```

Eu estou tentando executar as minhas *queries* dessa forma:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r(ManipulateData::select('SELECT * FROM vagas'));
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: E quais as outras informações da mensagem, tal como a linha que gerou o erro?

Comment: Porque não deixa tudo estático na classe `ConnectDB`? Já que fez assim no resto do código

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o erro esta apontando para o método `Connect::getPDO()'

Comment: Mas o método `getPDO` não é estático e você está chamando a partir de um estático. Se você não instanciou a classe, quem deveria ser `$this`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há de cara um erro conceitual. Quase todos os códigos PHP que eu vejo postados aqui cometem esse erro. As pessoas não entendem o que é herança e usam mesmo assim. Esta classe não deveria herdar da outra, não tem relação entre elas. Isto é gambiarra. Entendo que aprendeu assim porque quase todos os códigos PHP usando OOP estão errados. Por isso é melhor não usar OOP. Não use algo que não domina. Ferramentas só são boas quando você sabe usá-las. No seu caso, faça de forma mais simples que sairá um código melhor. E em PHP raramente OOP é uma vantagem, afinal ela é uma linguagem de *scripts*, não tem a mesma dificuldade de outras linguagens. E esse `ITemplate` parece inútil. Existem outros problemas conceituais na classe, inclusive o nome em inglês está errado, mas nem vou me atentar a isso porque a existência dela já é um erro. E não vi muito motivo para capturar uma exceção só para dizer que não conseguiu conectar e acabar com a aplicação. Captura de exceção deve ocorrer para fazer algo útil.

O erro é justamente o que foi dito, está usando o `$this` fora de um objeto. O `$this` é a variável do objeto, todos os métodos que acessam dados do objeto possuem esta variável, são os métodos de instância. Em métodos de classe esta variável não está disponível, portanto ela não existe, não pode ser usada. Seus métodos são todos estáticos, ou seja, todos de classe, e ainda não criou uma instância, portanto o `$this` não está disponível. Então não vai funcionar. Assim funciona:

```
class ManipulateData extends ConnectDB {
    public function select($query) {
        $stmt = $this->getPDO()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
$obj = new ManipulateData();
print_r($obj->select('SELECT * FROM vagas'));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/x1rQoz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/easxocsv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Inheritance.php).

Mas ainda é um conceito muito errado. Você poderia só plugar na tomada, mas está fazendo isto:

[image: Tomada cheio de penduricalho para encaixar o plugue]